# Laravel 9 - How to get resolved instance of task in Queue::before event?

Tags: laravel, queue

I have a multi-tenant project with multiple databases and a single queue. I need to switch between databases before running the job.

Here's the code I have:

```
    Queue::before(function (JobProcessing $event) {
        $customer = DB::table('customers')
            ->select('db_password', 'id')
            ->where('id', 11)
            ->first();

        DB::disconnect('mysql');
        config(
            [
                'database.connections.mysql.database' => 'customer_'.$customer->id.'_db',
                'database.connections.mysql.username' => 'customer_'.$customer->id,
                'database.connections.mysql.password' => Crypt::decryptString($customer->db_password),
                'customer.code' => $customer->id,
            ]
        );
        DB::reconnect('mysql');
    });
```

It's working, but in the where clause, the id must be dynamically set.
So I pass the id in the `Job::dispatch()` method, but here's the problem: how do I get the job instance to return the data inside it?

I saw in another question the `$event->job->instance` and `$event->job->getResolvedJob()`.

The first option is a protected property, so it doesn't work (it worked in Laravel 5). The second returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set public property or getter in your job, so you can retrieve your id from the job instance, like here in `getPodcastId`:

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Jobs;
 
use App\Models\Podcast;
use App\Services\AudioProcessor;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
 
class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
 
    /**
     * The podcast instance.
     *
     * @var \App\Models\Podcast
     */
    protected $podcast;
 
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\Podcast  $podcast
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Podcast $podcast)
    {
        $this->podcast = $podcast;
    }

    public function getPodcastId()
    {
        return $this->podcast?->id;
    }
 
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @param  App\Services\AudioProcessor  $processor
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(AudioProcessor $processor)
    {
        // Process uploaded podcast...
    }
}
```

But, to be honest, I think this is not really safe to change config on the go. The better solution would be to initialize another database connection inside your job and use it in your job dirrectly:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory;

// ...

public function __construct()
{
    $factory = app(ConnectionFactory::class);
    return $this->db = $factory->make(/* Config */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but the only problem with your answer is that I lose the functionality of serializing models in the constructor. In this case I would have to pass only the model identifier and return the model data within the task. Still, it's a valid approach, I'll think about it. Thank you again.